# How to hide all except first div referenced by an anchor href on click on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using anchor's `.hash` property as a selector to switch div state (show, hidden) of elements like:

```
  $('#navbar a').click(function(e) {
        $('.container > div').hide();
        $(this.hash).show();
        e.preventDefault(); //to prevent scrolling
    });
```

And  `<div>` elements:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="section1">Section 1</div>
  <div id="section2">Section 2</div>
  <div id="section3">Section 3</div>
  <div id="section4">Section 4</div>
</div>
```

It works, but not when page first loads, when it first loads, all divs are shown.

How to hide all divs except first one?

please take a look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/3G8tH/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with all but the first `<div>` hidden, then change which one is visible on click.

```js
$('#navbar a').click(function(e) {
    $('.container > div').hide();
    $(this.hash).show();
    e.preventDefault(); //to prevent scrolling
});
```

```css
.container > div {
    display: none;
}

#section1 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#section1">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section2">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section3">Link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section4">Link 4</a></li>  
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="section1">Section 1</div>
  <div id="section2">Section 2</div>
  <div id="section3">Section 3</div>
  <div id="section4">Section 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Trigger a click on the first one when the page is loaded:

```
$('#navbar a:first').click();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3G8tH/177/)**

Answer (score 0):

You want to zero in on the first `a` element or whichever element you want to default to and trigger a `click` event on it. This should do it:

```
$('#navbar a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $('.container > div').hide();
    $(this.hash).show();
})
.first().trigger('click');
```

```js
$('#navbar a').click(function(e) {
    $('.container > div').hide();
    $(this.hash).show();
    e.preventDefault(); //to prevent scrolling
})
.first().trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#section1">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section2">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section3">Link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section4">Link 4</a></li>  
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="section1">Section 1</div>
  <div id="section2">Section 2</div>
  <div id="section3">Section 3</div>
  <div id="section4">Section 4</div>
</div>
```